# Filtering data on timestamps

Tags: shell-script

this the log data :-

```
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:46 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1681   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_5f9cc4cc21704e0ebcc18ef6cdf7ba61_spot_train_flow_395_06_10_2023_00_01_37   hyp:12344   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:136149976401481415314412122   uid:5f9cc4cc21704e0ebcc18ef6cdf7ba61   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:50 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1230   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_27feb47a4b8f42a6b8608680435c65b7_spot_train_flow_864_06_10_2023_00_01_41   hyp:परमिट0928हैनंबर   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:5811310151586691127354813   uid:27feb47a4b8f42a6b8608680435c65b7   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:50 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:339   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_6070481eec99432a9a684aad9c4c8b85_spot_train_flow_785_06_10_2023_00_01_44   hyp:   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:4299191514141188512141013137   uid:6070481eec99432a9a684aad9c4c8b85   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:50 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1862   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_b586a3f777e94f4a9fca534b4527d029_pnr_number_input_flow_891_06_10_2023_00_01_38   hyp:   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:101313288321051313112158011   uid:b586a3f777e94f4a9fca534b4527d029   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:56 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:393   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_e5a6529e182c40078312611fc993443f_null_670_06_10_2023_00_01_52   hyp:null   language:mar   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:91413121061110711868601471214   uid:e5a6529e182c40078312611fc993443f   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:57 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:788   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_9181e4ce958a440ebda3c829bb7d61ae_pnr_number_input_flow_561_06_10_2023_00_01_48   hyp:   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:60131910914158249661421514   uid:9181e4ce958a440ebda3c829bb7d61ae   
### Fri Oct 06 01:01:12 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR+GASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:2909   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_30789c18f8464ad4a603201d9d3b9639_null_653_06_10_2023_01_01_06   hyp:null   language:ma   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:610611127151932773111101   uid:30789c18f8464ad4a603201d9d3b9639   
### Fri Oct 06 01:01:14 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:902   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_e7137e9291434309b79327bdb3d27ae8_null_849_06_10_2023_01_01_09   hyp:Telugu.   language:te   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:3326410111012112511010101335   uid:e7137e9291434309b79327bdb3d27ae8   
### Fri Oct 06 02:01:06 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:768   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_ac673c48e9874cd78f59175336c5ae49_null_215_06_10_2023_02_01_00   hyp:YES   language:en   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:1583121054711159129124151147   uid:ac673c48e9874cd78f59175336c5ae49
```

and i written in shell scripting language i want to filter data on basic of time like i m doing this:-

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file="MULTIPLE_ASR_INFO_2023_10_06.log"
output_file="output.log"

start_time="00:00:00"
end_time="01:00:00"

awk -F '[: ]' -v start="$start_time" -v end="$end_time" '$6 >= start && $6 < end && $(NF-3) > 2000' $log_file > $output_file
```

want the result like this :-

```
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:36 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1184   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_36b78ccd2d4e466fa6ac17784d4e98c4_null_864_06_10_2023_00_01_32   hyp:null   language:mar   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:15301312641246671545151215   uid:36b78ccd2d4e466fa6ac17784d4e98c4   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:46 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1681   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_5f9cc4cc21704e0ebcc18ef6cdf7ba61_spot_train_flow_395_06_10_2023_00_01_37   hyp:12344   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:136149976401481415314412122   uid:5f9cc4cc21704e0ebcc18ef6cdf7ba61   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:50 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1230   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_27feb47a4b8f42a6b8608680435c65b7_spot_train_flow_864_06_10_2023_00_01_41   hyp:परमिट0928हैनंबर   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:5811310151586691127354813   uid:27feb47a4b8f42a6b8608680435c65b7   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:50 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:339   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_6070481eec99432a9a684aad9c4c8b85_spot_train_flow_785_06_10_2023_00_01_44   hyp:   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:4299191514141188512141013137   uid:6070481eec99432a9a684aad9c4c8b85   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:50 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:1862   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_b586a3f777e94f4a9fca534b4527d029_pnr_number_input_flow_891_06_10_2023_00_01_38   hyp:   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:101313288321051313112158011   uid:b586a3f777e94f4a9fca534b4527d029   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:56 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:393   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_e5a6529e182c40078312611fc993443f_null_670_06_10_2023_00_01_52   hyp:null   language:mar   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:91413121061110711868601471214   uid:e5a6529e182c40078312611fc993443f   
### Fri Oct 06 00:01:57 IST 2023 ASR_MODE:ALL   ASR_USED:+MSASR   RECOGNIZE_TIME:788   RESULT_ASR:ALL   RESULT_ASR_TIME:0   fileName:ASR_REC_9181e4ce958a440ebda3c829bb7d61ae_pnr_number_input_flow_561_06_10_2023_00_01_48   hyp:   language:hin   serviceId:default_udialer_inbound   txnId:60131910914158249661421514   uid:9181e4ce958a440ebda3c829bb7d61ae
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. Linux is not UNIX and the tools available to the two systems are different. Do you need something that works on both Linux and UNIX systems?

Comment: In words, what are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/760752/edit). Do not respond here in a comment.)

Comment: Why can't you just compare your start and end times to the space-separated time field #5?

Comment: It's unclear what your additional filtering is being done on.  What do you want to capture with `$(NF-3) > 2000`?

Comment: Your timestamps can be parsed by `date` from `Gnu coreutils`.   `date -d 'Fri Oct 06 00:01:57 IST 2023' --iso-8601=seconds` will output `2023-10-05T20:31:57+02:00`.  Try something like `date -d 'Fri Oct 06 00:01:57 IST 2023' +'%H%M%S'` which will output `000157`.  Then you can can compare that integer to `010000` or `000000`.